# Fast calculation of transformation/rotation Marix 4x4

Tags: c++, opengl, eigen

I am working on a graphics engine. All of my models use a transformation matrix to place them in space.

But I have problems regarding execution speed.

I use this method:

```
Matrix4f* createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation, float rx, float ry, float rz, float scale) {
    Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Affine> t;
    t = AngleAxis<float>(rz, Vector3f::UnitZ());
    t.prerotate(AngleAxis<float>(ry, Vector3f::UnitY()));
    t.prerotate(AngleAxis<float>(rx, Vector3f::UnitX()));
    t.prescale(scale);
    t.pretranslate(translation);
    return new Matrix4f(t.matrix());
}
```

This is too slow for me. Anyone who knows a faster method?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, I would start with not allocating heap memory for that. Make the Matrix4f class copy-assign able. In general and unless some of the functions called here are implemented very bad, I don't think that this method can be the bottleneck of a rendering application.

Comment: Have you measured this code ? If so, where's the bottleneck ? What performance metric do you classify as slow / not slow ?

Comment: As @BDL suggests, avoid repeated use of new : preallocate objects on the stack. But in general when measuring performance you need to profile your code and see where the bottlenecks are rather than just guessing what parts you think are slow.

Comment: I have try remove allocation heap but it change nothing.I did my test manualy , i remove the 3 line of rotation and I pass from 30 to 400 FPS

Comment: Are the rendered objects still visible when you remove the rotation? If they aren't, then the fps change might be due to rendering less fragments. Measure how long the function really takes with a profiler to make sure that the function is the problem. Then find out with the profiler which part of the function takes too long and add that to your question.

Comment: @BDL Thx i go work on that

Comment: Sorry , i have find the probleme . Is just cause i compile on debug mode , if i compile in release mod i have 600 fps . Anyone can explain me for what ?

Comment: Debug contains more information in the compiled files (also greater in size); release is more optimized

Comment: Debug mode also doesn't apply optimizations that move the code around too much (i.e. most of them). That's why profilig debug builds is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. It was because I compiled in debug mode. If I compile in release mode it is not slow. Thanks for all your answers.